# WooCommerce - taxquery by product visibility outofstock shows also products instock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code in my plugin that is querying all products that are out of stock:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'nopaging'   => true,
    'fields'     => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => 'outofstock',
        'operator' => 'IN',
    ) ),
);

$out_of_stock_product_ids = get_posts( $args );
```

However, it also shows products, that have the product_visibility "instock". I can validate this by adding following code right after this:

```
    foreach ($out_of_stock_product_ids as $product_id) {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        echo $product_id . " - " . $product->get_stock_status() . "<br>";
    }
```

And the result is this:

```
118823 - outofstock
118536 - instock
118534 - instock
118121 - outofstock
117859 - outofstock
117350 - outofstock
116879 - outofstock
116877 - outofstock
```

Why does it show products with the stock status "instock", even though I am querying products that are only "outofstock"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WC_Product_Query` for this. Look at [docs](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query). Use `stock_status` parameter, here is [example](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#:%7E:text=products%20%3D%20wc_get_products(%20%24args%20)%3B-,stock_status,-Accepts%20a%20string).

```
// Get out of stock products.
$args = array(
    'stock_status' => 'outofstock',
);

$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

Then you can output it like this:

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
     echo $product->get_id() . " - " . $product->get_stock_status() . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: this seem to work. but it doesnt answer my question why the query I am doing doesnt return the intended result?

Comment: @vorwerg-ni this is strange because your code works for me.